# Are C#'s attributes better designed than Java's annotations?

Tags: c#, java, attributes, annotations, language-design

After reading this [old post from Clinton Begin](http://clintonbegin.blogspot.com/2008/02/clintons-java-5-rant.html) (creator of iBatis) I really wonder if his claims about annotations vs. attributes are widely accepted or if there is disagreement about it.

His points are:

- Annotations are not extendable
- No support for positional arguments
- Java-unlike definition syntax
- `annotation` is not a keyword (unlike `enum`)

Do those claims have merit and how does C# improve on that?

Comment: [archive available for this old post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110813174630/http://clintonbegin.blogspot.com/2008/02/clintons-java-5-rant.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well taken one by one those points obviously have merit:

- Attributes are classes you can extend and query as you wish. You can even add your own!
- Position arguments (I'm guessing you mean named arguments) are indeed possible with C#, with full Intellisense support.
- Can't really comment on how weird it looks, although coming from Razor it makes me think of macro expansion.
- Attributes don't have a keyword either, they're just a normal class.

That doesn't make Java's implementation worse, since they had a different goal in mind: backwards compatibility. C# had the advantage of building the language from scratch (and then progressing forward instead of maintaining strict backwards compatibility).

As a nit-pick though, nothing you or I mentioned are part of C#, they are part of the .NET runtime and can be found equally well in VB.NET and F#.